# R data.table : rolling lag sum for previous 3 days by group

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently working R in data.table and am looking for an easy way to implement a rolling lag sum. I can find posts on lags and posts on various sum functions but haven't been successful finding one in which sum and lag are combined in the way I am looking to implement it (rolling back 3 days).

I have a data set that resembles the following-

```
id  agedays  diar
1    1        1
1    2        0
1    3        1
1    4        1
1    5        0
1    6        0
1    7        0
1    8        1
1    9        1
1    10       1
3    2        0
3    5        0
3    6        0
3    8        1
3    9        1
4    1        0
4    4        0
4    5        0
4    6        1
4    7        0
```

I want to create a variable "diar_prev3" that holds the rolling sum of diar for the past 3 days prior to the current agedays value. Diar_prev3 would be NA for the rows in which agedays < 4  The data set would look like the following :

```
id  agedays  diar  diar_prev3
1    1        1      NA
1    2        0      NA
1    3        1      NA
1    4        1      2
1    5        0      2
1   6        0      2
1    7        0      1
1    8        1      0
1    9        1      1
1    10       1      2
3    2        0      NA
3    5        0      0
3    6        0      0
3    8        1      0
3    9        1      1
4    1        0      NA
4    4        0      0
4    5        0      0
4    6        1      0
4    7        0      1
```

I have tried a basic lag function, but am unsure how to implement this with a rolling sum function included. Does anyone have any functions they recommend using to accomplish this?

****Edited to fix an error with ID==2

Comment: Try `zoo::rollsum`

Comment: Don't you want to do this by `id` ? How is value at row 6 2?

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the logic; it does not appear to be by `id`, otherwise the results for id==2 don't make sense - but what is going on with id==3 and 4?

In principle, you could do something like this - either by ID or not:

```r
library(data.table)
library(RcppRoll)
DT <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                     agedays = c(1L, 2L, 
                                 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 
                                 5L, 6L, 7L), diar = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                       0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

setDT(DT)
DT[, diar_prev3 := ifelse(agedays < 4, NA, RcppRoll::roll_sum(lag(diar, 1), n=3L, fill=NA, align = "right"))][]
#>     id agedays diar diar_prev3
#>  1:  1       1    1         NA
#>  2:  1       2    0         NA
#>  3:  1       3    1         NA
#>  4:  1       4    1          2
#>  5:  1       5    0          2
#>  6:  2       6    0          1
#>  7:  2       7    0          0
#>  8:  2       8    1          1
#>  9:  2       9    1          2
#> 10:  2      10    1          3
#> 11:  3       2    0         NA
#> 12:  3       5    0          1
#> 13:  3       6    0          0
#> 14:  3       8    1          1
#> 15:  3       9    1          2
#> 16:  4       1    0         NA
#> 17:  4       4    0          1
#> 18:  4       5    0          0
#> 19:  4       6    1          1
#> 20:  4       7    0          1
DT[, diar_prev3 := ifelse(agedays < 4, NA, RcppRoll::roll_sum(lag(diar, 1), n=3L, fill=NA, align = "right")), by=id][]
#>     id agedays diar diar_prev3
#>  1:  1       1    1         NA
#>  2:  1       2    0         NA
#>  3:  1       3    1         NA
#>  4:  1       4    1          2
#>  5:  1       5    0          2
#>  6:  2       6    0         NA
#>  7:  2       7    0         NA
#>  8:  2       8    1          1
#>  9:  2       9    1          2
#> 10:  2      10    1          3
#> 11:  3       2    0         NA
#> 12:  3       5    0         NA
#> 13:  3       6    0          0
#> 14:  3       8    1          1
#> 15:  3       9    1          2
#> 16:  4       1    0         NA
#> 17:  4       4    0         NA
#> 18:  4       5    0          0
#> 19:  4       6    1          1
#> 20:  4       7    0          1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: apologies, I edited to fix id==2. The previous id==2 should have been id==1. Thanks!

Comment: I get an error when I run this : "Error in `[.data.table`(MPC_anthro, , `:=`(diar_prev3, ifelse(agedays <  : 
  Type of RHS ('logical') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)". The variables agedays and diar are both integers. ID is a character. Any idea what I should do to fix this? I also tried removing the 1 and replaced it with 1L. This still errored.

Comment: The error does sound like `agedays` is not numeric, so that is strange. Does it work with the reprex I posted?

Comment: user12728748 No it still doesn't work right. However I was able to get it to work without the ifelse statement. I just dealt with the agedays < 4 following the creation of the rolling sums. So everything worked out fine!